# jekyll projects are not aligned

Tags: css, jekyll

I started experimenting with Jekyll to setup a personal page and I have stumbled upon a weird issue: When adding a 4th project, it is not correctly aligned.

Here is the `projects.yml` file:

```
- name: A scalable Grid Computing framework for extensible phylogenetic profile construction
  i18n: name
  url: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/307585591_A_Scalable_Grid_Computing_Framework_for_Extensible_Phylogenetic_Profile_Construction
  img: /static/assets/img/landing/springerLink.png
  desc: Published by SpringerLink, this paper presents my design and implementation of a distributed framework that can exploit Grid infrastructure resources (EGI) to scale-up common genomics workflows. Achieved a 30x speed-up compared to serial implementations.

- name: Robotics Simulation
  i18n: name
  gh_user: steremma
  repo: stdr_simulator
  img: /static/assets/img/landing/stdr.png
  desc: Integrated a new GUI into a robotics application written in C++ and implemented several design and performance optimizations. The project is currently distributed as an official ROS package.

- name: Natural Language Processing
  i18n: name
  gh_user: steremma
  repo: gensim
  img: /static/assets/img/landing/gensim.png
  desc: I have contributed to one of the most popular Python open source packages in Topic Modeling called Gensim. My work includes adding features that made it into a subsequent release, fixing bugs, and improving the documentation of complex model implementations.

- name: GPU accerelated Convolutional Neural Networks 
  i18n: name
  url: https://gist.github.com/steremma/048549de16cc48610233c943ecf495b4
  img: /static/assets/img/landing/google.png
  desc: Designed and implemented a fully functional Convolutional Neural Network library in CUDA currently integrated in ROOT, the data processing framework written by and used at CERN. The library allowes the timely processing of particle physics experimental data. My implementation consistently outperforms the previous CPU version by a factor of 3, as its performance and memory footprint is comparable to those of Keras.
```

And here is the result:

[image: Screenshot of the relevant part]

Obviously the bottom left project is not aligned. How can I fix it?

Comment: What theme are you using? Do you have something in _layouts ? Any repo?

Comment: This is an html/css problem and with no code it's difficult to debug.

Comment: Here is the repo: https://github.com/steremma/steremma.github.io
I didn't change any html or css code yet.

Comment: Its a css issue. Because the height of each project is different the issue occurs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I love the structure of your Jekyll project. Great job. You were almost there. You wrote:

```
{% assign loopindex = forloop.index | modulo: 2 %}
```

... but you did nothing with this loopindex variable (AFAIK). This custom loopindex variable can be used to determine when you need to start a new row. You need to replace the above code (line 9 in projects.html) with:

```
{% assign loopindex = forloop.index | modulo: 2 %}
{% if loopindex == 1 && forloop.index != 1 %}
  </div><div class="row">
{% endif %}
```

This instructs Liquid to close the row after every (modulo) two items if there is a third. The exception is needed for the first item (we do not want to start with an empty row).

PS. You might want to look at [JekyllCodex](https://jekyllcodex.org) for more great code examples.

Comment: My current "solution" was to add more text to the smaller project in order to make their end height equal. Your idea sounds like an actual solution, so I will test and update ASAP. Thank's for your time and kind words!

Comment: You are welcome. Adding more text works too... but is less of a real solution indeed.